# Determine destination location of apt-get install <package>?

Tags: apt, software-installation, tomcat, locate

For some applications its fairly easy enough to locate where the application was installed to using the "which" command.  However, some applications such as Tomcat are a little out of my league to locate.

I'm asking for particular methodology that can be applied to any apt-get install  to locate where the binary, library, and support files are installed to.

The cause of this question is that I installed Tomcat7 and I can's seem to locate it and I have a list of customizations to perform.

Comment: Note that I found where tomcat7 is installed soon afterwards by installing apache2 and then visiting the default page @ localhost:8080 but there is more than that which is shown on that page.  Searching the filesystem via the "search:" option in the folder browser found plenty more.

Comment: Also informative: [How to find application's path from command line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28555/how-to-find-applications-path-from-command-line)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can run the command `dpkg -L package` to list all the files in the package. For example `dpkg -L ubuntu-minimal` will only list a couple of small files related to packaging, as it is only an empty meta-package that depends on other packages.

```
dpkg -L tomcat7
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  I'll have to read up on man dpkg since I've been neglecting to do so as it seems.

Comment: This is a lifesaver for an unfamiliar java library!  I didn't even know the name of the file to look for with `locate`...  Now I can update my classpath.

Comment: hello pal , do you know the alternative in fedora 29

Comment: Only works if it is installed already? Correct? Because it does not work for me.

Answer (score 27):

You can list the contents of an installed package with the [`dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg.1.html) command, which is the low-level package manipulation command that the APT tools call internally:

```
dpkg -L tomcat7
```

You may want to search in the output; use the [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/grep.1.html) command. For example, to see the configuration files (which live under `/etc`):

```
dpkg -L tomcat7 | grep /etc
```

The files you want to modify may be in dependencies of the main `tomcat7` package. Searching inside a package and its dependencies is more complicated. It's likely that the files you're looking for are in some package called `tomcat7-something`. The easiest way to display them is with the `apt-file` command, which is not installed by default (install it with `apt-get install apt-file`).

```
apt-file list tomcat7
```

[`apt-file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/apt-file.1.html) lists file names in all packages in Ubuntu (according to the package sources you have enabled), whether they are installed or not. You can also use it to search for a file:

```
$ apt-file search RequestInfoExample.java
tomcat7-examples: /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/examples/WEB-INF/classes/RequestInfoExample.java
```

Comment: I'll have to try apt-file sometime before installing stuff.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

What I usually do is:

- Start Synaptic (you will need to install it first)
- find the package I'm interested in
- right click, select Properties
- view the list of installed files

Answer (score 0):

I see many responses rightly saying "dpkg -L " is the command for listing content of an installed package. But, none of them have answered the other question, why does "which" command list empty for some of the packages? The answer is; "which" displays the location of an executable alone, not all the content of the package. In case, a package does not contains any executable, then "which" display empty. For example, openssl package provides an executable with the same name for various cryptographic operations. Whereas, libssl-dev package contains development lib, not any executable.